# Swagger PHP - Describe array of objects

Tags: swagger, openapi

I use **Laravel** + **Swagger PHP**. In one of my services, I handle parameters like this :

```php
$params = [
    'addressChild' => [
        'address' => ' ... ',
        'city' => ' ... ',
    ],
    'addressParent' => [
        'address' => ' ... ',
        'city' => ' ... ',
    ],
];
```

I am trying to describe this schema in Swagger Annotations, using **OpenApi 3** :

```php
/**
 * @OA\Post(
 *      path="/entity/{entity}/addresses",
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          @OA\JsonContent()
 *      ),
 *      @OA\RequestBody(
 *          description="Addresses to store",
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              type="object",
 *              @OA\Property()
 *          ),
 *      ),
 * )
 *
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

I tried many things like :

```php
 @OA\JsonContent(
     type="object",
     @OA\Property(name="addressKid", ref="#/components/schemas/ParkingAddressRequest") // error
 ),
```

My address data is described in `ref="#/components/schemas/ParkingAddressRequest"` schema, how can I set it as an array in `RequestBody` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you could do it like this

```php
/**
 * @OA\Post(
 *      path="/entity/{entity}/addresses",
 *      @OA\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          @OA\JsonContent()
 *      ),
 *      @OA\RequestBody(
 *          description="Addresses to store",
 *          required=true,
 *          @OA\JsonContent(
 *              type="array",
 *              @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/ParkingAddressRequest")
 *          ),
 *      ),
 * )
 *
 */
```